# Pushing values to an array inside an array of array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm a bit confused on how to push a value inside an araay which is part of an array of arrays.

The situation i have i sthe following.

I have two arrays :

The first (`$suggestedRestaurantsGoogleResponse`), is an array of google places responses like the following :

```
^ array:2 [▼
  0 => array:25 [▶]
  1 => array:25 [▶]
]
```

The second (`$foundRestaurants`) is the result of a DB query as the following :

```
^ array:2 [▼
  0 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1273 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => App\Models\Restaurant {#1263 ▼
        #fillable: array:2 [▶]
        #connection: "mysql"
        #table: "restaurants"
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #with: []
        #withCount: []
        +preventsLazyLoading: false
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
        #attributes: array:5 [▼
          "id" => 3
          "created_at" => "2022-04-26 18:57:21"
          "updated_at" => "2022-04-26 18:57:21"
          "property_id" => 1
          "google_place_id" => "ChIJfy613ThgLxMR-Kr1iDROgrU"
        ]
        #original: array:5 [▶]
        #changes: []
        #casts: []
        #classCastCache: []
        #attributeCastCache: []
        #dates: []
        #dateFormat: null
        #appends: []
        #dispatchesEvents: []
        #observables: []
        #relations: []
        #touches: []
        +timestamps: true
        #hidden: []
        #visible: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
    ]
    #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  }
  1 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1254 ▶}
]
```

What i need to achieve is to insert inside the `$suggestedRestaurantsGoogleResponse[i]`, the attributes of the `$foundRestaurants[i]` so what i have thought to do is the following :

```
$suggestedRestaurantsGoogleResponseWithId = array();

        foreach($suggestedRestaurantsGoogleResponse as $dataResponse){
            foreach($foundRestaurants as $place){
                foreach($place as $foundPlace){
                    array_push($dataResponse,  $foundPlace->getAttributes());
                    array_push($suggestedRestaurantsGoogleResponseWithId, $dataResponse);
                }
            };
        };
```

But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work properly as if i `dd($suggestedRestaurantsGoogleResponseWithId)` i get the following :

```
 array:4 [▼
  0 => array:26 [▶]
  1 => array:27 [▶]
  2 => array:26 [▼
    "address_components" => array:8 [▶]
    "adr_address" => "<span class="street-address">Via di S. Cosimato, 14</span>, <span class="postal-code">00153</span> <span class="locality">Roma</span> <span class="region">RM</s ▶"
    "business_status" => "OPERATIONAL"
    "formatted_address" => "Via di S. Cosimato, 14, 00153 Roma RM, Italy"
    "formatted_phone_number" => "06 580 0353"
    "geometry" => array:2 [▶]
    "icon" => "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/restaurant-71.png"
    "icon_background_color" => "#FF9E67"
    "icon_mask_base_uri" => "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/restaurant_pinlet"
    "international_phone_number" => "+39 06 580 0353"
    "name" => "Da Vittorio a Trastevere"
    "opening_hours" => array:3 [▶]
    "photos" => array:10 [▶]
    "place_id" => "ChIJ0YUORThgLxMRsjt84lb-KUk"
    "plus_code" => array:2 [▶]
    "price_level" => 2
    "rating" => 4.3
    "reference" => "ChIJ0YUORThgLxMRsjt84lb-KUk"
    "reviews" => array:5 [▶]
    "types" => array:4 [▶]
    "url" => "https://maps.google.com/?cid=5272024487934311346"
    "user_ratings_total" => 1204
    "utc_offset" => 120
    "vicinity" => "Via di San Cosimato, 14, Roma"
    "website" => "http://www.davittorioatrastevere.it/"
    0 => array:5 [▼
      "id" => 3
      "created_at" => "2022-04-26 18:57:21"
      "updated_at" => "2022-04-26 18:57:21"
      "property_id" => 1
      "google_place_id" => "ChIJfy613ThgLxMR-Kr1iDROgrU"
    ]
  ]
  3 => array:27 [▼
    "address_components" => array:8 [▶]
    "adr_address" => "<span class="street-address">Via di S. Cosimato, 14</span>, <span class="postal-code">00153</span> <span class="locality">Roma</span> <span class="region">RM</s ▶"
    "business_status" => "OPERATIONAL"
    "formatted_address" => "Via di S. Cosimato, 14, 00153 Roma RM, Italy"
    "formatted_phone_number" => "06 580 0353"
    "geometry" => array:2 [▶]
    "icon" => "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/restaurant-71.png"
    "icon_background_color" => "#FF9E67"
    "icon_mask_base_uri" => "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/restaurant_pinlet"
    "international_phone_number" => "+39 06 580 0353"
    "name" => "Da Vittorio a Trastevere"
    "opening_hours" => array:3 [▶]
    "photos" => array:10 [▶]
    "place_id" => "ChIJ0YUORThgLxMRsjt84lb-KUk"
    "plus_code" => array:2 [▶]
    "price_level" => 2
    "rating" => 4.3
    "reference" => "ChIJ0YUORThgLxMRsjt84lb-KUk"
    "reviews" => array:5 [▶]
    "types" => array:4 [▶]
    "url" => "https://maps.google.com/?cid=5272024487934311346"
    "user_ratings_total" => 1204
    "utc_offset" => 120
    "vicinity" => "Via di San Cosimato, 14, Roma"
    "website" => "http://www.davittorioatrastevere.it/"
HAVE ALOOK AT THE BELOW :
        0 => array:5 [▼
          "id" => 3
          "created_at" => "2022-04-26 18:57:21"
          "updated_at" => "2022-04-26 18:57:21"
          "property_id" => 1
          "google_place_id" => "ChIJfy613ThgLxMR-Kr1iDROgrU"
        ]
        1 => array:5 [▼
          "id" => 4
          "created_at" => "2022-04-26 20:39:11"
          "updated_at" => "2022-04-26 20:39:11"
          "property_id" => 1
          "google_place_id" => "ChIJ0YUORThgLxMRsjt84lb-KUk"
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

Both arrays `$foundRestaurants` and `$suggestedRestaurantsGoogleResponse` have the same order, this means that if I have on the first place of `$foundRestaurant` the record regarding the restaurant with ID = 1, in the `$suggestedRestaurantsGoogleResponse` at the first place there's the detail response for the restaurant with ID = 1.
From the above dd(), it seems to duplicate each array value and also, in the the duplicate he's inserting the attributes for both restaurants found.

Sorry for the long stuff i posted but i hope that you have clear my idea.

Is there anybody who has an idea of what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: There isn't anything other than the index, linking the two datasets together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've wrote and what you want is different. Try this one:

```
$suggestedRestaurantsGoogleResponseWithId = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($suggestedRestaurantsGoogleResponse); $i++) {
  $suggestedRestaurantsGoogleResponseWithId.push($foundRestaurant[i]->map(function($item) {
    return array_map(function($foundPlace) {
      return $foundPlace->getAttributes();
    },
    $item);
}))
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.